# Could not create unique index "" when I use string PK

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I have the following entities:

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class FamilyTree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(FileName))]
    public File File { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
 }
```

My `ApplicationDbContext.cs` has the following configuration:

```
...
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<FamilyTree>() 
            .HasOne(x => x.File)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<FamilyTree>(x => x.FileName)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
...
```

Now I'm trying to make a migration and apply:

```bash
$ dotnet ef migrations add
$ dotnet ef database update
```

But I see the following error:

```
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 23505
    MessageText: could not create unique index "IX_FamilyTrees_FileName"
    Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
    SchemaName: public
    TableName: FamilyTrees
    ConstraintName: IX_FamilyTrees_FileName
    File: tuplesort.c
    Line: 4295
    Routine: comparetup_index_btree
23505: could not create unique index "IX_FamilyTrees_FileName"
```

What is wrong?
I use .NET 6 and postgres

Comment: I am guessing that whatever data already exists in the table 'File' has a duplicate 'Name', and therefore you can't create a non-duplicate index.   A string is a very unusual type to use as a primary key.   Generally a PK is a integer or Guid.

Comment: @Neil thanks. In my case, that was string. Why not? File name is a GUID + extension. So, file name is unique,

Comment: I'm not saying a string can't be used, it's just unusual.  Generally, you would have a guid or integer as PK, then a unique index on the field or fields that should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just had data in the `FamilyTrees` table that interfered me to perform the migration somehow. What a pity that I did not receive an appropriate message.